# Conditionally calling Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I am running JQUERY SORTABLE -- then serialising the result ---then using AJAX to post the serialised array to a php database update script.

It all works as it should. However I wish to condition the AJAX call (shown in the script below) to run once only --- ie when all the SORTABLE sorting is done and hence I have a final serialised array.

The serialization and ajax script is as below-but posts every time the serialised array is updated rather than when the final array is ready. Any ideas would be hugely welcome. (Would consider ideas on how best to implement an HTML BUTTON to give effect to this conditionality manually).

```
    <script>

                $('ul').sortable({
                        update: function (event, ui) 
                    {
                        var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');      
                         $('span').text(order);//test serialize without ajax-works fine

    //ajax curently runs each time a sort operation is serialised. 
    //I want to run AJAX when I have finished sorting hence serialization.                          
                            $.ajax({
                              url: 'update_gallery_grid.php?propertyid='+ propertyid +'&product='+ product +'&payment='+payment,//url data needs to be GOT on the pageAJAX pots too 
                              type: 'post',
                              data: order, 

                            success:function(result){
                                $(".result").html(order);}, //works but gives serialised array each time serialisation is updated by sortable. No conditionality.                                   
                               error: function(){
                            alert('something bad happened');
                              }

                            }); // end ajax call

                    }

                 });     

    </script>
```

EDIT
Further to Twisty's idea I have come up with this edited. However it isn't posting Ajax at all now - so Ive made an error in moving form the original code posted (which did post) and this new edit. Have I done something silly here?

```
                <script>

                $(function() {
                  $('#saveBtn').button().click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                //ajax is not posting on Save. It was posting to php with initial code in question. So Ive messed something up here?
                                $.ajax({
                                      url: 'update_gallery_grid.php?propertyid='+ propertyid +'&product='+ product +'&payment='+payment,//url data needs to be GOT on the pageAJAX pots too 
                                      type: 'post',
                                      data: data,

                                    success:function(result){
                                        $(".result").html(data);},

                                      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                                        console.log(xhr);
                                        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                                      }
                                }); // end ajax call
                      });   //end click 

                //following sorts and reports array to $(span) ok     
                 $('#sortable').sortable({
                    //placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                    update: function(event, ui) {
                      var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                      $('span').text(data);
                    }
                  });
                  $("#sortable").disableSelection();

                });//end function


                </script>
```

EDIT 2
Twisty-I have moved the var data declaration as shown below. The effect is that sortable isn't sorting and the save doesn't yield anything in results div.

```
                 $('#sortable').sortable({
                    //placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                    update: function(event, ui) {
                    //var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                      $('span').text(data);
                    }
                  });
                  $("#sortable").disableSelection();

                 var data = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');

                });//end function
```

This is the output string and sorting doesn't now change it as it did on prior edit (although no post). Still no result at all (no Firebug post200 listing) on Save.

```
  Query string: item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10 Result:
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're searching for in an answer. What have you tried?

Comment: To be honest I am a little stumped. So I am looking for good ideas as to how to do this. I cant believe its not a common problem but i can find nothing on google that addresses it. So I'm open to any ideas from the community here.

Comment: How do you know when the user is done sorting?

Comment: It maybe a user interaction Kevin. Maybe a button. Or possibly a maximum of ten sort changes (but that's a bit complicated) . Was looking for ideas really. Must be a pretty common issue this one. Surprised I could find no posts addressing it head on. Posting each time a sort is partially changed really messes up the updater logic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement an action based on a button, you may consider the following:

**jQuery**

```
  <script>
  $('#saveBtn').button().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = 'update_gallery_grid.php?propertyid=' + propertyid + '&product=' + product + '&payment=' + payment;
    $.ajax({
      url: targetUrl,
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(order)
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $('#result').html("<p>Order: " + order + "</p><p>Results: " + result + "</p>");
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $('#result').append("<p>" + error + "</p>");
      }
    });
  });

  $('#sortable').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();

  var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
  </script>
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1f1tq1h3/

Since your example did not include the HTML, I used the jQuery UI Demo. You can see it all in the example. We are simply moving the AJAX activity to a Click event versus the Update event.

Comment: Thanks for this Twisty. Let me have a play with it for an hour or so and see where it takes me . By the way how do I give you a mark up on here??

Comment: You can Upvote or Downvote answers if you find them helpful. If this answers your question, you can mark it as the answer by clicking the check on the left hand side of the answer. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I am going to Upvote you because your Fiddle is pretty close Twisty. I have merged your solution with my original code creating an edited script which I've added to my question. It does sort but unfortunately it is now not posting the data from Ajax at all (checked in Firebug and no post200 on Save). Have I done something obviously silly?

Comment: The variable that you create, `data`, is out of scope. Basically, the callback function will not know  what this variable is, and it will be `undefined`. This is why, in my example, `order` is defined outside the initialization of the button and sortable. This allows it to be available to both.

Comment: Here is the query string: item[]=5&item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10 .....This  is the sorted data variable output in the HTML span tag. So the serialisation works ok. However should I now move the var data=lsjfisfiohfiohfoi to where you did for the purposes of the Ajax call? If that works its the answer :)

Comment: I think I have solved the issue and it was related to the way i was declaring the URL. Your code works nicely now. So I would like to accept your answer Twisty.

Comment: @WChris great to hear! Feel free to upvote and mark this as the answer

Comment: ..so I have accepted the answer but it wont show up on this question because those of us with a measly newbie reputation don't get to see the answers we accept on our questions. Not sure why that is. But ACCEPTED.

Comment: Give it 15 minutes :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ha I did accept again but still says I'm too lowly a reputation. I will have another go tomorrow. And thank you!!!